# Error when using gfortran on MacOS

Tags: macos, fortran, gfortran

I mostly work on linux and have no problems but want to occasionally use a Mac for work. Somehow gfortran does not work there, though. I installed it as instructed but when I try to compile something, this happens:

```
gfortran -o m_g_matrix2.x m_g_matrix.f90
ld: entry point (start) undefined.  Usually in crt1.o for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have no idea what this means and google search did not help. Did someone manage to get gfortran to work on Mac?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: From where did you install it? Which instructions did you use? Did you read the question about mac and gfortran from this site? There are many http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/osx+gfortran

Comment: I read the questions and they do not answer mine. All I'm gathering is that people in general have problems compiling fortran on a Mac. It was a few months ago that I installed gfortran so I do not remember the exact way just that I needed Xcode for it

Comment: Have you installed OS X Yosemite since you built gfortran?

Comment: No, there have been no updates to the OS since then and it hasn't worked from the beginning.

Comment: Cannot reproduce -- gfortran built from source via macports, MacOS 10.10, 10.9 and 10.6.

Comment: I uninstalled it and reinstalled it from here:
https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranBinaries#MacOS
Same problem.
Would you care to explain how you installed it with macports so it works?

Comment: I just do `sudo port install gcc48` and the command `gfortran-mp-4.8` works fine.

Comment: Thanks, now it works! Odd that the binary wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed gcc binaries for yosemite from http://hpc.sourceforge.net
and also installed Xcode command-line tools as directed there.
gcc contains the gfortran compiler.
Seems to work well on macbook air with Yosemite.
JTN